# Super object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, class

I am working on creating a class for the first time, and I am facing difficulties here and there, first read my code, and I will post the error after it

```
 import random

class card_deck:
     suites= ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
     ranks= ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
               "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
def __init__(self, rank, suite, card):
    self.rank= rank
    self.suite = suite
    self.card = card
def card_list(self):
      suites= ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
      ranks= ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
          "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
def ranks(self):
    return self.rank
def suite(self):
    return self.suite
def card(self,card):
    return self.card
def __str__(self):
    return (Card.ranks[self.rank],
                         Card.suits[self.suit])




def value(self):
    if self.rank == 'Ace':
        return 1
    elif self.rank == 'Jack':
        return 11
    elif self.rank == 'Queen':
        return 12
    elif self.rank == 'King':
        return 13
def shffule(self):
    random.shuffle(self.card)
def remove(self,card):
    self.card.remove(card)
def __getitem__(self,i):
    return self.card_list()
def append(self,value):
    super(card_deck,self).append(value)
    return self


def cardremaining(self):
    self.suite-self.rank




 def main():
  try:
      rank = []
      suite = []
      card = []
      deck = card_deck(rank,suite,card)
      deck.shffule()
      #drup=[]


       for i in ['Spades','Hearts', ' Diamonds','Clubs']:
          for c in ['Ace','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','Jack','Queen','King']:
              deck.append([c, i])



      hand = []
      user =eval(input('Enter a number of cards: 1-7 '))
      print()
      while user <1 or user >7:
          print ("Only a number between 1-7:")
          return main()

      for i in range(user):
           hand.append(deck[i])
           print(hand)
  except ValueError:
      print("Only numbers")
      main()
```

Here is what I get when I run main()

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#64>", line 1, in <module>
     main() File "/Users/user/Desktop/deck_class.py", line 66, in main
     deck.append([c, i])
   File "/Users/user/Desktop/deck_class.py", line 44, in append
     super(card_deck,self).append(value)
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'append'
```

so even if I try to remove super and just write slef.append(value) I get another error it which python keep printing

```
File "/Users/user/Desktop/deck_class.py", line 44, in append
     card_deck,self.append(value)
   File "/Users/user/Desktop/deck_class.py", line 44, in append
```

I did research before posting the question I tried to fixing it my self, but it just feels too complicated for me, and I am hoping you guys can help! so what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `card_deck` in not inheriting from any class that has `append` method, then why are you using `append` on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting the impression that you're trying to make a `card_deck` object that is *pretending* to be a list of some sort. I also feel that you're trying to make your `card_deck` object act as two separate things: a deck of cards, and a single card.

Taking that in mind, it would be far simpler to take a step back, split up your code into two separate classes, and do something like the below. I left comments in the code to explain my thought process:

```
import random

class Card(object):
    '''Remember, a 'card' is completely different from a deck. You can have a 
    card that is not contained in a deck, and a deck is simply another object
    that contains one or more cards, with a few convenience methods attached.'''

    def __init__(self, rank, suite):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suite = suite

    def __repr__(self):
        '''The different between '__repr__' and '__str__' is not particularly
        important right now. You can google the difference yourself.'''
        return "Card({0}, {1})".format(self.rank, self.suite)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} of {1}".format(self.rank, self.suite)

    def value(self):
        ranks = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
            "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]

        # This is something called a 'dictionary comprehension'. It lets you
        # map the rank of the card to its corresponding value. 
        #
        # 'enumerate' is a built-in. Try doing `enumerate(["a", "b", "c", "d"])`
        # in the shell, and see what happens.
        values = {rank: i + 1 for (i, rank) in enumerate(ranks)}

        return values[self.rank]

class Deck(object):
    '''Now, we have the deck.'''

    def __init__(self):
        self.suites = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
        self.ranks = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
             "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]

        # Here, I've chosen to create a full deck when instantiating the object.
        # You may chose to modify your code to pass in the cards you want instead.
        #
        # Notice how we're keeping track of all of our cards inside of a list.
        # This way, we're free to write whatever methods we want, while still 
        # internally representing our deck of cards in the cleanest manner possible.

        self.cards = []
        for suite in self.suites:
            for rank in self.ranks:
                self.cards.append(Card(suite, rank))

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def remove(self, card):
        # idk if this will actually work -- you should test it.
        self.cards.remove(card)

    def append(self, card):
        '''In this method, we're taking a card, and adding it to our deck.
        We've written the entire thing ourselves -- no need to call to super
        (which doesn't work, in any case)'''
        self.cards.append(card)

    def get_top_card(self):
        '''This is a common operation when dealing with decks -- why not add it?'''
        return self.cards.pop()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[" + ", ".join(repr(card) for card in self.cards) + "]"

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(str(card) for card in self.cards)


def main():
    deck = Deck()
    deck.shuffle()

    hand = []


    while True:
        user = int(input('Enter a number of cards: 1-7 '))
        print()
        if not 1 <= user <= 7:
            print ("Only a number between 1-7:")
        else:
            break

    for i in range(user):
        hand.append(deck.get_top_card())
    print(hand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now, you may be wondering what `super(card_deck,self).append(value)` was actually doing in your original example. Calling `super(card_deck, self)` will return the **parent class** of the `card_deck` class -- in other words, the class `card_deck` inherits from.

In this case, your class isn't inheriting anything (technically, it inherits the built-in "object" class, but every class inherits from `object`, so that's moot).

Then, when you call `append`, you're trying to call the `append` method that exists inside the parent class of `card_deck`. However, no such method exists, so your code throws an exception.

In your case, since you're just beginning to use classes, I would strongly recommend that you ignore inheritance and the 'super' builtin function for now. It's overkill, and will only confuse you when you're trying to get a grip on object-oriented programming. Focus instead on writing good objects that provide good methods that manipulate variables you define yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really know what super() means? super could call the function from classes where current class inherited from.  i.e:

```
class card_deck(list)：
   ....
   super(..).append(...)
   ....
```

there are also some bugs in your script

```
def __getitem__(self,i):
    return self.card_list()
```

actually you dont use i in the function.

If this is the first time you write a class and you are new to python. I suggest you start from some simply classes and try using simple functions to reach your goals.You dont need to use `__getitem__` or `super()`. They will just confuse you if not understood correctly.